# Find a suitable method to obtain time based similarity percent?

Tags: percentages, time-series

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcqCR.png)

The question is described in the attached picture.

Comment: What does this have to do with Linear Algebra????????

Comment: rate of change using algebric method also matches this issue!
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/rates-of-change-and-behaviors-of-graphs/#:~:text=The%20units%20on%20a%20rate,change%20in%20the%20input%20values.

Comment: You need to do a much better job of explaining what you are after. We do not live in your mind, and have no idea what you are asking unless you explain it clearly. In particular what do you mean by "that considers the time series variation also". How is it supposed to "consider the series variation"?

Comment: Sorry about that I am trying to do the best I can to explain it clearly. Kindly check the question again. I hope it would be clear now